# can I start a remote node process from vscode?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I'm currently debugging a node app in a raspberry pi remotely from vscode in my laptop.  It's awesome.

I am going to a terminal connected to the raspi and starting the node app, then I'm attaching the vscode debugger.  Whenever I change the code I have to go to the terminal, kill the node app, and start it again. Going back and forth from the terminal to vscode is a pain.

I want to restart the raspi node app from just vscode to start each debug cycle.  I know you can do this from a node app on localhost but I can't figure out how to do this remotely.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?